# Is there any way to conduct an online survey?

Tags: civicampaign, civisurvey

According to Civi Documentation, "CiviCampaign has a feature that enables offline surveys...", which implies that there is no way to "send" a survey to a group/set of contacts (like online event registrations). Is this correct, or is there a way to create a survey, and send it to a group/list, etc. of contacts to complete & submit the survey?

Using CiviCRM version 5.52.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can conduct a simple survey in civicrm by creating a Profile with the Custom Fields you need for the survey, and then either expose this form publicly or send out a link with a checksum to give existing contacts access to the form without needing to re-enter their contact details

Comment: I think part of the issue here is the term 'survey'. if you look at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/survey/add?reset=1 you may get a better idea of what CiviCampaign is offering. If you are just trying to do something like SurveyMonkey, ie a form, rather than person-to-person interviews, then you can easily do this just with a Profile

Comment: Good information; Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Webform CiviCRM is pretty good fur surveys, if you're using Drupal.

Comment: Using Joomla, but thank you!